# List contains method not type safe

Tags: java, generics

While going through this question: "[Checking if an object is contained within a linkedlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955973/checking-if-an-object-is-contained-within-a-linkedlist)", I realized that user was trying to pass a String argument to the contains method of a LinkedList of type LinkedList:

```
    LinkedList<LinkedList> list = new LinkedList<LinkedList>();

    list.contains("String");
```

This doesn't throw any compilation error because the 'contains' method accepts java.lang.Object and passing a string value to it is allowed.

So just out of curiosity, I wanted to understand why was this method chosen to accept 'Object', when it could have been restricted to accept only the list type (just like add). Isn't it defeating the whole purpose of Generics i.e. "Stronger type checks at compile time"?

Comment: here is a good read on this topic http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073330/the-contains-trap-in-java-collections.html

Comment: Related, or rather duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857420/what-are-the-reasons-why-map-getobject-key-is-not-fully-generic and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you have a `BankAccount` identified by `AccountId` (both are classes, neither extending the other).

Let's now say you have `LinkedList<BankAccount> accounts;` and want to see if there's an account with a given ID.

Now, `AccountId.equals()` could accept `BankAccount` and compare itself against the account's ID. With this, you'll be able to call `accounts.contains(account_id)` and it'll just work even though the argument to `contains()` has a type that's completely unrelated to the collection's type.

Comment: You say BankAccount identified by AccountId, but neither extending the other.. Not really following it. Can you provide some more details, so as to understand it better?

Comment: Yes. Remeber to make BankAccount.equals accept AccountId as well  since equals should be symmetric. From equals documentation: It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

Comment: I'd consider it as **highly** dubious to implement two different classes in a way that one instance of one class can be `equals` to an instance of the other class. Many reasonable usage patterns could break with such an implementation. (This refers to classes that are not "equal" in terms of a common interface that they implement)

Comment: I agree with the purpose, but not with the suggested implementation. The contract of the hashCode states that If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result (equals is also reflexive). So the proper way should be overriding both, the equals and the hashCode method and not depending on accepting classes.

Comment: @newacct This is what my last statement referred to: In this case, both objects are "a list", and the `equals` method has to be implemented in a way that makes them "compatible", regardless of the implementation. But in the proposed case, the objects/classes are unrelated, meaning that they do not have a sensible common ancestor.

Answer (score 4):

The specification for the contains method says:

> returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`
>   [docs oracle][1]

However, it also says that it might throw a `NullPointerException` if the collection doesn't permit null elements or a `ClassCastException` if the type of the specified element is incompatible with this collection. These are marked as `optional`.

Furthermore, it also says that:

> Many methods in Collections Framework interfaces are defined in terms of the equals method

but:

> This specification should not be construed to imply that invoking Collection.contains with a non-null argument o will cause o.equals(e) to be invoked for any element e

Therefore, my conclusion is that this is some kind of hack to allow implementations define different behaviours (e.g. accepting null elements) and optimizations (e.g. overriding the equals method of a class so you can check if an element is contained in the collection without having a reference to it).

I'll explain the latest with an example:

```
public class A {

   public void initialize() {
      // Lots of code and heavy initialization
   }

   public String id;

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
     return id.hashCode();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return this.hashCode() == o.hashCode();
   }
}
```

And then:

```
SomeCollection<A> collection = new SomeCollection<A>(); 

// Create an element and add it to the collection
A a = new A();
a.initialize(); // Heavy initialization
element.id = "abc";
collection.add(a);

// Check if the collection contains that element

// We create a second object with the same id, but we do not initialize it
A b = new A();
b.id = "abc";

// This works for many common collections (i.e. ArrayList and HashSet)
collection.contains(b);
```

Actually, there are more methods like `indexOf(Object o)` and `remove(Object o)` which follow this. So I don't think it's for compatibility, but it's made on purpose to allow for this kind of solutions.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 3):

Simple... LinkedList is actually an Object.

Furthermore,

Say you have a map for each of your linked list:

- CustomMapItem 1: LinkedList 1
- CustomMapItem 2: LinkedList 2
- CustomMapItem 3: LinkedList 3

Because `contains()` takes an Object as a parameter, you are able to set your `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods for CustomMapItem so that you can locate your corresponding LinkedList.

Comment: >If you set the contains method to take a generic you'd strip away its object properties. Thus, you'd lose the ability to make your own hashcode() and equals() methods<<<< Could you explain? I'm not following.

Comment: I agree with the usage of the equals and hashCode, but not with your statement about stripping away object properties. You can still override the equals and hashCode method in the generic and its subclasses. Actually, you can create an instance of a subclass with the same hashCode as a generic instance contained in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the contains method does not modify the underlying collection so it does not have a strict requirement like add method.

More importantly though, contains deals with object equality. It actually invokes the equals method on the elements of the list. It might seem that for two objects to be equal they need to be at least of the same type but that's not really the case. It totally depends on how well your equals method is defined.

An example:

```
List<A> myList = new LinkedList<A>();
...
B b = new B();
myList.contains(b); //expected true if 'value' attribute is equal.


class A {
     int value;
     public boolean equals(Object object){
        if(object instanceof A && ((A)object).getValue() == this.value)
        return true;
        else if(object instanceof B && ((B)object).getValue() == this.value)
        return true;
        else
        return false;

}
```

And similarly

```
 class B {
     int value;
     public boolean equals(Object object){
        if(object instanceof A && ((A)object).getValue() == this.value)
        return true;
        else if(object instanceof B && ((B)object).getValue() == this.value)
        return true;
        else
        return false;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply for backward compatibility.  Although generics are useful for restricting the contents of a collection to a homogeneous type, it is still a valid use case to have a collection contain heterogeneous objects if you so choose.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<String> homogeneousStringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    homogeneousStringList.add("Foo");
    homogeneousStringList.add("Bar");

    List heterogeneousObjectList = new ArrayList();

    heterogeneousObjectList.add("Foo");
    heterogeneousObjectList.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    heterogeneousObjectList.add(new Date());

    System.out.println(homogeneousStringList.toString());
    System.out.println(heterogeneousObjectList.toString());
}
```

Produces the following output:

[Foo, Bar]

[Foo, 1, Sun Sep 21 00:36:59 MDT 2014]

Comment: That's not the point, if you don't specify the generic type, it will be Object by default. And actually every List is heterogeneous since inheritance exists.